# how to refresh asynchronous views on page change in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have an application that loads data only once in $(document).ready. There are links between collection view and model view. Views have asynchronous architecture, therefore they render on page refresh. But when I click on the links nothing renders because data is already fetched and no events are fired. Is there a plugin or trick that allows to handle both situations?

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.lazyLoad = function (id) {
    var model = this.get(id);
    if (model === undefined) {
        model = new this.model({ id: id });
        this.add(model);
        model.fetch();
    }
    return model;
}

var Col = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Model,
});

var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var ColView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render);
    }
});

var ModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.on('change', this.render);
    }
});

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "colView",
        "col/:id": "modelView"
    },

    colView: function () {
        new ColView(collection: col);
    }

    modelView: function (id) {
        new modelView(model: col.lazyLoad('modelId'));
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    col = new Col;
    col.fetch();
    app = new AppRouter();
});
```

Comment: We need to see more code here.  Do you have event handlers defined for the links?  What do the links do? What are you expecting them to do?

Comment: Collection view have links for each model. Links are managed by AppRouter, i.e. when I click on 'col/modelId' link the modelView is created. But this view renders only when model send 'change' event. It doesn't happen because all data are fetched early.

Comment: I expect follow behaviour: if (page 'col/modelId' is refreshed by <F5>) { render model on 'change' event when data will be fetched } else { render model immediately }

Comment: @user1469049 you can always do a `view.render();` call to have it rendered. Posted a snippet below to clarify

Comment: @user1469049 that's not very helpful without seeing the code that you've written to handle this.  as it stands right now you have no events wired into anything so I wouldn't expect anything to work

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand, you want it to render and show the view, but because `col` has already been fetched this doesn't trigger a `change` event which you bound to `ModelView's` render event. Well you can always call ModelView's render yourself.

```
modelView: function (id) {
    var view =  new modelView({ model: col.lazyLoad('modelId') });
    view.render();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work when user refreshes page. When view.render() is called model is not yet fetched.

Comment: @user1469049: Then fix your `render` logic to do something sensible (such as render an empty template or a spinner) if the model isn't there yet and then let the appropriate event trigger another `render` call.